# How to launch Process Explorer

Tags: process-explorer

I installed a Sysinternals' utility called [Process Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Explorer).

I am not able to see the utility. Where do I need to go to run Process Explorer?

Comment: How about making the title of your question a question?

Comment: Are you saying you lost track of where you copied the `procexp.exe` to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't get added to the Start Menu or Quick Launch.  You need to run it from wherever you saved the executable.  The .exe filename is procexp.exe, look for that and double-click it.

Comment: There is also a option in process explorer to replace task manager, then it launches when you hit c-a-d and select task manager.  This is my preferred method.

Comment: ctrl-shift-esc for a one-stop task mgr launch.

Answer (score 3):

Most Windows system administrators have a directory called C:\bin which houses all the useful tools that one needs, like Process Explorer, [Far Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_Manager), grep, 7-Zip, ... And then that is added to the environment variables. Then you can launch anything you use regularly using <kbd>windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and typing the name of the executable.

To edit the environment variables, go to *Start* → *Control Panel* → *System* → *Advanced* → *Environment Variables*.

OR just use <kbd>windows</kbd> + <kbd>pause/break</kbd> to open system properties.

Comment: To clarify, need to add a C:\bin entry to the PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to run Sysinternals tools, I find, is to use the "Live" website, i.e. http://live.sysinternals.com/procexp.exe

This way you don't have to download/install it on any computer.

Comment: This assumes your computer has unfettered access to the live.sysinternals.com webserver. On a server placed in the DMZ, this is very likely not true.